# How does this code add a string to an array list and return it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I came across this code that succinctly adds a bookName to an array list and returns the list, but I don't understand how it works under the hood. I've never seen a function take parameters and simply returns the arguments. How does it actually add bookName to the list?

Code:

`function add(list, bookName) { return [...list, bookName]; }`

Comment: the spread operator (`...`) adds the list to an array (`[]`) in the return statement, along with the bookName. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: @Tzvi2 Thanks! Didn't notice it was actually returning an array

Comment: (The spread operator usage shown does not really exhibit “functional programming”.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three dots `...` are called a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and they unpack the items in the `list` parameter, and then add them to a new array (`[ ]`) with `bookName` at the end, which is then `return`ed by the function.